# Creating company object using Intuit Anywhere

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am creating an Intuit Anywhere backed application for QuickBooks platform. I have gone through the IPP documentation and found out that we can create Company object for QuickBooks for Windows using IDS API (https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/Company).

However, I am confused as if it is possible to create a company object without connecting to Intuit using 'Connect to QuickBooks' widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Furhan,
The "Connect to QuickBooks" widget is a widget which kicks off the 3 legged Oauth flow, where by the end customer will authorize your application to access their QuickBooks data. and return an Oauth Access Token and RealmId to your application.

So going through this connect flow is a prerequisite for being able to make any REST API Calls.

thanks,
Jarred

Comment: The example that he linked to specifically shows NOT using OAuth. Instead it uses an INTUIT AUTH header. How can you even go through the "Connect to QuickBooks" process if you don't yet have a Company? (e.g. you're trying to create one)

Comment: which example is he referencing? I think it has been edited. INTUIT AUTH headers are only if you were federated and using the ticket authentication. In the Intuit Anywhere model, there is only Oauth authentication.

Comment: Read his question and click the link he posted: https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/Company There's a huge section titled "Creating a Company" that he referenced which talks about INTUIT AUTH headers for creating a company.

Comment: @KeithPalmer: I am a bit confused with this conversation. Can we create a company without "Connect to QuickBooks" process?

Comment: I don't know - that's what I was trying to get @JarredKeneally to answer. The docs sure make it seem that way... but it's not unusual for the docs to be incorrect.

Comment: @JarredKeneally: Please share what you think of this scenario.

Comment: Yes you can create a company, and yes you need to go through the connect to QuickBooks flow to get an Oauth access token needed to call that API.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a company file?